# Conditionally showing a parameterized route's output for the root route of an Ember.js app?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, web-applications, routes, url-routing

I'm customizing an existing Ember.js 1.11 app. (I can modify its code, but I'd like to keep any changes to a minimum, if possible.)

It has a route like `/item/:itemName/:itemId` for displaying info about a specific item.

In some cases, I'd like to have the root route (i.e. `/`) display info about a specific item instead of the root route's default content.

That is:

- Browsing to `hxxps://example.com/` would show the default content in some cases.
- In other cases, going to `hxxps://example.com/` would show the same content as `hxxps://example.com/item/item-name/12345`, but the browser should still show the URL as just `hxxps://example.com/`.
- The item page would still be accessible at `hxxps://example.com/item/item-name/12345` like usual, too.

I can somewhat achieve this by having the root route conditionally use `replaceWith('/item/item-name/12345')` to transition to the item route when loading, but that causes the URL shown in the browser to change (which I don't want to have happen in this case).

I could not find a way to perform a transition while still leaving the URL unchanged.

I also considered defining the route mapping differently in each case, along the lines of:

```
...
this.route('item', { path: '/item/:itemName/:itemId' });

if(is_showing_default_root_route_content) {
    this.route('root', { path: '/' });
}
else {
    this.route('/item/item-name/12345', { path: '/' });
}
...
```

But that doesn't seem to work, and maybe it doesn't even make sense to do.

Is there a clean way to:

1. Transition to another route without changing the URL shown by the browser? or,
2. Have the root route output the content of a separate parameterized route?

Comment: You may modify a `model` hook of your root route and return a model that you need to show